# Pegar INPUT_GET de url amigável

Tags: php, url-amigável

Olá, meu sistema possui dois painéis. Um do Admin sem qualquer otimização em SEO, outro do usuário, onde ele pode postar artigos e mais. Acontece que eu uso uma query para buscar a pasta e retorna o arquivo requisitado através da url.

Acontece que meu sistema front está otimizado, sendo assim, as terminação dos arquivos .php foram removidas para SEO. Tornando a URL abaixo inutilizável

Exemplo:

***meusite.com/usuario/dashboard.php?get=artigos/criar***

note que o dashboard.php faz a requisição da pasta artigos e do arquivo criar dentro dela, porém retorna 404. Agora vamos supor que eu troque "?" por & e retire o .php da URL o arquivo é retornado corretamente. Ficando assim:

***meusite.com/usuario/dashboard&get=artigos/criar***

isso não é recomendado, então, como proceder? Obrigado a ajuda.

Sobre o script que remove o .php é uma função geral,então não há checagem de pasta ou algo do tipo.

Comment: não é melhor assim: `meusite.com/usuario/dashboard?get=artigos/criar` ou `meusite.com/usuario/dashboard/artigos/criar`
?

Comment: Desse jeito ele não pega a query, por causa a ausência o .php na URL

Comment: Você falou url amigavel, presumir que iria usar .htaccess, se usar .htaccess é possivel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se só tiver 1 parametro para agarrar pode fazer:

`meusite.com/usuario/dashboard&get=artigos/criar`:

```
$param = explode('&', $url); // array('meusite.com/usuario/dashboard', get=artigos/criar)
$param = explode('=', $param[1])[1]; // artigos/criar
```

Mas atenção que pode ter vários parametros:

EX: `meusite.com/usuario/dashboard&get=artigos/criar&get2=miguel`:

```
$params = explode('&', $url); // array('meusite.com/usuario/dashboard', 'get=artigos/criar', 'get2=miguel')
$gets = array();
for($i = 1; $i < count($params); $i++) { // atenção que não precisamos do index 0 do array params
    $param = explode('=', $params[$i]);
    $gets[$param[0]] = $param[1];
}
// $gets = array('get' => 'artigos/criar', 'get2' => 'miguel');
```

Comment: Miguel, gostei da tua solução, só uma dúvida. Falando de segurança, existe alguma falha para invasão na url meusite.com/usuario/dashboard&get=artigos/criar&get2=miguel , abraços

Comment: Não se você fizer as verificações necessárias, que são examente as mesmas que faz, ou deveria fazer, com o metodo convencional `$_GET`

Comment: Por ex: Se estiver à espera de um parametro que se chame `get` e outro que se chame `get2`. Deve sempre `if(isset($_GET['get']) && isset($_GET['get2'])) { .. tudo ok... else { .. não está tudo ok .. }`

Comment: Valeu Miguel, nesse sistema uso PDO com todas as verificações possíveis sobre segurança.

Comment: Não. PDO diminui as probalidades só isso, as verifições devem ser sempre feitas antes de qualquer operação na base de dados

Comment: Ou mesmo que não vá operar na BD mas vá fazer outra ação qualquer no seu programa que dependa disso